# MySQL IF deciding multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case

Depending on a complicated condition, I need to insert one or the other set of fields.

What I would like to do is (pseudo code)

```
IF (condition) DO
  INSERT INTO table set columnA= "foo", columnB = "bar"
ELSE
  INSERT INTO table set columnA= "no foo", columnB = "no bar"
ENDIF
```

Unfortunately I can't use stored procedures and I have to fit this into a regular statement.

I could repeat the condition for every column

```
INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB) SELECT IF(condition, "foo", "no foo"), IF(condition, "bar", "no bar")
```

But the conditiion itself is complex and nested, so I'm trying not to repeat it.

Is there a syntax that lets a single IF or CASE decide multiple columns ?

Comment: can't you move the condition to where clause?

Comment: How does this branching end up in a SQL query instead of an application? If this were only a query, without an application, you would already know the value of condition. If you're building this query and inserting parameters, you can do it in the application.

Comment: @Fabricator: Unfortunately there won't be a where claus where clause to handle the condition.

Comment: @Marcus: The SQL stateent is the output of a legacy application that I can't change. I can only specify a template for an SQL statement where the app inserts values into placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.  But it would appear that your condition is independent of the rows.  You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(columnA, columnB)
    select (case when flag = 1 then 'foo' else 'no foo' end),
           (case when flag = 1 then 'bar' else 'no bar' end)
    from (select <condition> as flag) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are your friends ;-)

```
 INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB)
 SELECT IF(@condition:=<your condition goes here>, "foo", "no foo"),
        IF(@condition, "bar", "no bar");
```

Not that you can use `EXISTS(SELECT something)` as a valid condition

Answer (score 0):

You do get a `WHERE` clause with a `SELECT ... FROM`:

You can break it into two separate queries, but, it's two queries:

```
INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB)
SELECT 'foo', 'bar'
WHERE :foo;

INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB)
SELECT 'no foo', 'no bar'
WHERE NOT :foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
  INSERT INTO table 
    SELECT "foo", "bar" FROM something WHERE (condition)
    UNION
    SELECT "no foo", "no bar" FROM something WHERE NOT(condition)
```